# Install Java 8 dpkg was interrupted

Tags: dpkg

I'm trying to install Java 8 following the bellow links

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-678-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04/
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-oracle-java-6-7-8-on-ubuntu-13-10/

But this is what I get

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

sudo apt-get update

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

The truth is I tried first `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` but it took way to long so I stop it after a while. No if I run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8b121-0~webupd8~0) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
```

Even if I run

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail && sudo apt-get update
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Also I saw it in another question so I tried it.

```
ps aux | grep apt | grep -v 'grep'
root      2597  0.0  0.7  35084 14732 ?        SNl  18:26   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/aptd
```

Could someone explain me why is this happening, and what this `lock` and `dpgk`?

Comment: Usually you get a lock if you are running without sudo or another instance of apt-get or a graphical program such as software center. See also http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do was to restart my system and run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Installation was interrupted, so that was the reason for those messages.